# Skipping my Login activity with no reason

Tags: java, android

My problem is the title
As soon as I have done Login activity, it skips my Login activity, it shows the main activity without sign in.

Before i code in Login activity, it ran normally, meaning that the Login activity would show 1st

Here my code

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private TabsAccessorAdapter tabsAccessorAdapter;

    private FirebaseUser currentUser;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser=mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        mToolbar= findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("F9");

        viewPager= findViewById(R.id.main_tabs_paper);
        tabsAccessorAdapter= new TabsAccessorAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(tabsAccessorAdapter);

        tabLayout= findViewById(R.id.main_tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if(currentUser==null)
        {

            SendUserToLoginActivity();
        }
    }
    private void SendUserToLoginActivity() {
        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(loginIntent);
    }
}
```

LoginActivity

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseUser currentUser;
    private Button LoginButton,PhoneLoginButton;
    private TextInputLayout UserEmail,UserPassword;
    private Button CreateNewAccount ;
    private TextView  ForgetPassword;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser=mAuth.getCurrentUser();



        InitializeFields();
        CreateNewAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SendUserToRegisterActivity();

            }
        });
        LoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AllowUserToLogin();
            }

        });


    }
    private void AllowUserToLogin() {
        String email=UserEmail.getEditText().getText().toString();
        String password=UserPassword.getEditText().getText().toString();

        if(email.isEmpty()||!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Enter a valid email address...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(password.isEmpty() || password.length() < 5){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Password should be at least 6 character",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(password.isEmpty()&&email.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter your email and password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            progressDialog.show();
            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                SendUserToMainActivity();
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Successful!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                String message = task.getException().toString();
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Error:  "+ message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                    });

        }

    }

    private void InitializeFields() {
        LoginButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
        PhoneLoginButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoginByPhone);
        UserEmail = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.emailLogin);
        UserPassword = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.passwordLogin);
        CreateNewAccount=(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);
        ForgetPassword=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.forgetpasswordLogin);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    }


    /////Neu da dang nhap se chuyen den trang mainactivity
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if(currentUser !=null)
        {

            SendUserToMainActivity();
        }
    }
    private void SendUserToMainActivity() {
        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(loginIntent);
    }
    private void SendUserToRegisterActivity() {
        Intent registerIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,RegisterActivity.class);
        startActivity(registerIntent);
    }
}
```

RegisterActivity

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button CreateButton,AlreadyHaveAccount;
    private TextInputLayout UserEmail,UserPassword;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        InitializeFields();

        AlreadyHaveAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SendUserToLoginActivity();

            }
        });
        CreateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CreateNewAccount();
            }

        });
    }
    private void CreateNewAccount() {
        String email=UserEmail.getEditText().getText().toString();
        String password=UserPassword.getEditText().getText().toString();

        if(email.isEmpty()||!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Enter a valid email address...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(password.isEmpty() || password.length() < 5){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Password should be at least 6 character",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(password.isEmpty()&&email.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter your email and password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            progressDialog.setMessage("Creating.....");
            progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            progressDialog.show();
            //Ket noi FireBase tao email mat khau
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(this,new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        SendUserToLoginActivity();
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Account Created Successfully...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        String message = task.getException().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Error:  "+ message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                }
            });


        }
    }
    private void InitializeFields() {

        CreateButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);
        UserEmail = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.emailRegister);
        UserPassword = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.passwordRegister);
        AlreadyHaveAccount=(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonHaveAccount);
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
    }
    private void SendUserToLoginActivity() {
        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(loginIntent);
    }
}
```

I think the problem is in the LoginActivity, because when I wrote some code in it, the problem arose

Comment: I couldn't make sense of your first couple of sentences. Could you explain them more in detail?

Answer (score 1):

Once the user is logged in, onStart will send the user to mainActivity
You need to create a logOut button in MainActivity, So it will not skip login page

you can also clear data of the app from the devices to make the `currentUser == null`

for logout
`FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
 auth.logOut();`